# Does a ValidatedMethod is hidden from client if not in server folder?

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods

For bdd CRUD i write my Collection.insert , update, etc in a ValidatedMethod (mdg:validated-method) and call these methods from the client.

```
//  /object/methods.js
export const insertObject = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'insertObject',
  run({object}) {
    ObjectCollection.insert(object);
  },
});

//  /object/view.js
import {insertObject} from './methods.js'

insertObject.call(object , callback());
```

Is the bdd operation code protected (not on the client) by the used of Validatedmethod? Despise the import of the file.

Or do i need to put bdd code in a /server directory?

It bugs me cause on https://github.com/meteor/todos the crud methods are not in a /server folder, exposing them to the client...

note: unsecure package is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import a method to client code, that method will be visible to client side. To avoid that you could just use `Meteor.call` or `Meteor.apply` to execute the method.